# Count the number of vowels in an array in PHP

Tags: php

In PHP I have written a script to count the number of vowels in an array and output the result.

When running the script I get an `Undefined offset` error.

What is wrong with this code?

```
for($a = 0; $a < count($expld); $a++) {
    for($b = 0; $b < strlen($expld[$b]); $b++) {
        if ($expld[$b] == 'A' || $expld[$b] == 'a' || $expld[$b] == 'E' || $expld[$b] == 'e'
            || $expld[$b] == 'I' || $expld[$b] == 'i' || $expld[$b] == 'O' || $expld[$b] == 'o'
            || $expld[$b] == 'U' || $expld[$b] == 'u')
        {
            $vowel++;
        }
    }
    echo "$expld[$a] has $vowel vowels(s).<br> ";
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It shows an error when I input. Shulz was here. 
Undefined offset: 3 in C:\wamp\www\Maglana_SW02template.php on line 24

Comment: That is probably because you are indexing `$expld` with `$b`, instead of `$a`. Also, the indexing is wrong when checking the characters.

Comment: Yes I tried to use strlen($expld[$a]) but it seems to worsen the errors.

Comment: You also could use `strtolower` then you wont need to check for uppercase vowels.

Comment: Improved question. Improved code formatting

Comment: @Shulz, posted the answer, shorter form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you quite messed up the indexing, check it out:

```
for($a = 0; $a < count($expld); $a++)
{
    $vowel = 0;
    for($b = 0; $b < strlen($expld[$a]); $b++)
    {
        if($expld[$a][$b] == 'A' || $expld[$a][$b] == 'a' || $expld[$a][$b] == 'E' || $expld[$a][$b] == 'e'
        || $expld[$a][$b] == 'I' || $expld[$a][$b] == 'i' || $expld[$a][$b] == 'O' || $expld[$a][$b] == 'o'
        || $expld[$a][$b] == 'U' || $expld[$a][$b] == 'u')
        {
          $vowel++;
        }
    }
    echo "$expld[$a] has $vowel vowels(s).<br> ";
}
```

Comment: Oh my  !  I never thought this is going to be 2 Dimensional Array !

Comment: Well, it is not, but virtually you can represent a string as an array of characters :)

Answer (score 2):

Just as another possible solution. You can use regular expression:

```
$stringToTest = implode($expld);
$vowelsCount = strlen(preg_replace('/[^aeiouAEIOU]/', '', $stringToTest));
```

Here we removed from the string everything except vowels and then counted rest of the characters (which should be a vowels only).

Comment: Wow I think that's the shortest code I've ever seen.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the character exists in vowels array. This way you don't have to do lengthy check! Here is a code to do so...

```
// vowels
$vowels = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');

for ($a = 0; $a < count($expld); $a++) {
    // init count
    $vowel_count = 0;

    for ($b = 0; $b < strlen($expld[$b]); $b++) {
        if (in_array(strtolower($expld[$a][$b]), $vowels)) {
            $vowel_count++;
        }
    }
    echo "$expld[$a] has $vowel_count vowels(s).";
}
```

Hope this is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, a few observations:

- You seem to be not properly using the $a and $b indexes; your second for-loop is ignoring where it is in $a! Since you're iterating through each string in an array, the safer bet may be to use a foreach-loop instead (one less thing to keep track of)
- You aren't defining your vowel count, so it wouldn't show 0. Furthermore, since you're not resetting your vowel count, the count would keep increasing

Here is a sample that utilizes a foreach-loop (tested in PHP 5.4+):

```
$input = "Charles Schultz was here";

// Instead of adding a large if-elseif-elseif-... statement, define
//   the vowels in an array, then check if the value is in that array
$vowels = array('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U');
$exploded = explode(" ", $input);

foreach($exploded as $string) {
    // Reset the counter for each word
    $count_vowels = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
        if(in_array($string[$i], $vowels)) {
            $count_vowels++;
        }
    }
    echo "$string has $count_vowels vowel(s).<br />";
}
```

Comment: That foreach is more advance I've not known that yet but it is more/less smiliar to forloop. I'm still striving to learn this php. For more efficient, can I  use toLower() here ?

Comment: @Shulz - It's similar to a for-loop, but something to keep in mind (especially with beginning PHP) is to keep your code _readable_. The foreach loop is easy to read (for each element in an array and each element represented as $string...) and it helps simplify your code. As for using strtolower, it wouldn't hurt, but at a small scale like this, it wouldn't really matter. You'd want to call it on $input before exploding, then just remove the upper-case vowels in the $vowels array.